# how to access a folder present inside project in cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a folder named 'Images' present in my project .The path to that folder is `'/Users/username/Documents/Test/ProjectName/Images'`.
How to access the images folder in cocoa app.
Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity asking: why do you need to access the folder? when u can actually access the files

Comment: This folder is not in your project. That's path to folder in your drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to work with files and folders in bundle of your app, you could access resources folder with call:

```
NSURL *resourceURL [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL];
```

Than you could work with resourceURL, reading content of folder with help of `NSFileManager`, as you do with regular folders and files on disk.

But that's barely needed. Usually you take resource from bundle by file URL which you obtain with call like:

```
NSURL *fileUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"user agreement" withExtension:@"rtf"];
```

Have a look in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) about other variants to take paths for resources from app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly by this

```
 NSButton *closeButton = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(185,215 , 15, 15)];
 [closeButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"close.png"]];
```

the close image is now displaying in the button..

this may help you...